# how to calculate cumulative probability for *dependent* events?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

The formula for cumulative probability for independent events is easy enough.   Just multiply the probability of the events together.  For example, 2 independent events, each with a probability of 0.80 would have a cumulative probability of 0.8 * 0.8 = 0.64.  But I need to figure out the formula to determine cumulative probability for *dependent* events.  For example, what is the probability of both Event A and Event B occuring if they are both dependent on each other?  Let's say that Event A has a probability of .80 and Event B has a probability of 0.90.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can say that $0.7 \leqslant P(AB) \leqslant 0.8$, and nothing else - for any number $x \in [0.7, 0.8]$ there are events $A$ and $B$ with $P(A) = 0.8$, $P(B) = 0.9$, $P(AB) = x$.

There is also notion of conditional probability - by definition, $P(AB) = P(A) \cdot P(B | A) = P(B) \cdot P(A | B)$.